# G is the Cantor set, $X$ is a countable set of G hence G\X is dense

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing, cantor-set

> **Exercise**: Let $G$ be a Cantor set.
>
> a) Prove that $G$ has a countable dense subset.
>
> b)If $X$ is a countable subset of $G$ then $G\setminus X$ is dense in $G$

a)
It is know that the Cantor set for example the ternary Cantor set has the same cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ despite its length is $0$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ are dense set in $\mathbb{R}$ and $G$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with uncountable elements hence $G\cap\mathbb{Q}$ must be a countable dense subset of $G$.

b) I have no concrete idea on how to taclkle the question of countability and density in an abstract set $X$.

**Questions**:

**1)** Is my proof insofar right? If not. Why not?

**2)** How is b) solved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the first question: the cantor space $2^{\omega}$ is clearly a Polish space, so you conclude. To see that it is Polish, consider that it is the countable product of the space $\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology and this is a Polish space, so it is Polish.

Comment: for the second question: $X$ countable implies that $2^{\omega}\setminus X$ is uncountable.Then it is dense if and only if, for every open set $A$, $A\cap (2^{\omega}\setminus X)\neq \emptyset$ , but then an argument from infinite combinatorics show you that it cannot be empty.

Comment: Not every Cantor set in the reals contains any rationals. The srtandard one contains plenty of them, and they do form a dense set. It does require some reasoning. Just compactness of $C$ implies it's separable.

Comment: Let $H$ be the set of all irrational numbers. Since $\mathbb Q$ is a dense set in $\mathbb R$ and $H$ is an uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$, can you conclude that $H\cap\mathbb Q$ is a countable dense subset of $G$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compact metric space is separable, so the Cantor set is too. For a concrete dense set in the Cantor set: take all the end points of the intervals in the construction: at stage $0$ we have $[0,1]$ and we add $0$ and $1$ to the dense set; at stage $1$ we have $[0,\frac13]$ and $[\frac23,1]$ and we add $\frac13,\frac23$ to the dense set; at the next stage we add $\frac{1}{9}, \frac29, \frac79, \frac89$ etc. In the end we get all "rationals" in the ternary expansion: all those numbers (that have only $0$ and $2$'s in a ternary expansion) that are eventually periodic.

All non-empty open subsets of $C$ are uncountable (they all contain sets homeomorphic to the whole Cantor set, even), so all of them intersect the complement of any countable set.

Comment: I have a question. Let $X$ be a closed subset of the Cantor set. Then $\Bbb R\setminus X=\bigsqcup_{n\in \Bbb N} I_n$, where each $I_n$ is an open interval of $\Bbb R$. Is it true that $\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb N}\partial I_n$ is a countable dense subset of $X$?

Comment: Also, is it true that for each point $x\in X$, there exists a sequence $\{p_n\}\subseteq \Bbb R\setminus X$ convering to $x$?